# Meteor js Iron router - How to redirect after signin?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm running Meteor version 1.1.0.2 and iron router.

What is the proper way to redirect to a user profile page after successful login?

After a successful login I use `Router.go('templateName')` which gives me the error:

`Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login'` .

How to correctly redirect using iron router ?

Code snippet is here: http://pastebin.com/Dm4FWrSr

Browser console errors are here: http://pastebin.com/VR46zeKC

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the route, try with this.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err,result){
 if(!err){  //use this if there is not error redirect them.
   Router.go('home')
  }else{
   console.log(err.reason) //should print the error
  }
})
```

Comment: I've updated the links above based on your comments. No effect. I've posted the error(s) I'm seeing in the browser console.

Comment: are you sure email and password are the corrects values? check answer update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. It was b/c the name of the route that I had defined was 'Home' and not 'home' . Simple enough but it would have been easier to find the error had there been a 'route 'home' not defined message ..'.

In any case,  I redirected to my user profile login path

```
Route.go('/user');
```

instead of `Route.go(<missing route>);`

And now successful logins redirect just fine.